# split_part in Hive - undefined

Tags: python, sql, hive

This is the error I got. I am running some SQL code within the python environment as follows and the error message states that the function `split_part` is not a built in function. However when I run my DB notebook I find that I don't need to specify it.

```
sql = """

insert into {click_table}(
  ...
  , context_page_url
  , help_title
  
)
select 
    event_header_event_id
  , event
  ...
  , split_part(cs.context_page_url, '/', 7) as stem
from table


""".format(click_table=click_table, daysback=daysback)
```

and running with `data = spark.sql(sql)` leads to the following

```
AnalysisException: Undefined function: split_part. This function is neither a built-in/temporary function, nor a persistent function that is qualified as spark_catalog.default.split_part.
```

Below are my includes

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('clickstream').getOrCreate()
```

Comment: There is nothing as `split_part()`. There is `split()` or `get_splits()`.

Comment: @KoushikRoy The code works just fine when running in data bricks natively with `%sql`.